# It's 2012, are people still using Eclipse for Android? What about emulators?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I know the IDE question has been asked before, but I'm hoping there are new IDEs/options available to developers. Eclipse is too slow/unstable, even with my 8 GB of RAM.

Also, do we have any other options for emulators? The Android emulators, aside from being slow, I find is not a real world simulator of an Android device.

This is my first post on Stack Overflow, and hopefully by opening up older questions I haven't broken any of the rules.

Comment: Can you be more specific with your definition of "unstable"? Are you getting errors that you can describe? Can you put them in a bug report? :-)

Comment: As a side comment, I'd recommend using Genymotion now for emulation purposes: www.genymotion.com

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have 4GB on Windows 7 x64, AMD PhenomX2 and Eclipse it is not slow. I would suggest modifying `eclipse.ini` to give more RAM memory to eclipse :

```
-Xms512m
-Xmx768m
-XX:MaxPermSize=768m
```

You could also have a look at this blog post : [Eclipse and memory settings](http://blog.xam.dk/?p=58).

As for the `AVD`, the emulators run better than before, but still if you want to simulate an 3.1+ Platform Device, you'll be in serious problems, since it is very slow. So as you said, it's 2012, you should probably test on some real devices.

Answer (score 2):

There are other IDEs and emulator solutions out there.

For IDE Check : http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/

Other Emulation Option : http://www.android-x86.org/

By the way, I use eclipse and AVDs! :)

Answer (score 2):

> I'm hoping there are new IDEs/options available to developers

Nobody is forcing you to use an IDE. I wrote three books on Android application development using a plain ol' text editor and the command line. The only reason I use Eclipse now is because it's drag-and-drop GUI building support now makes it so compelling to developers that I feel I have to cover Eclipse more in my books.

> Also, do we have any other options for emulators? The Android emulators, aside from being slow, I find is not a real world simulator of an Android device.

The closer you get to hardware, the more the emulator will behave like an emulator. Outside of that, it is as "real world" as you are going to get. For things where the emulator is insufficiently "real world" or is too slow (e.g., tablets, video playback), test using an Android device. All devices that legitimately have the Android Market on them are capable of serving as app development test devices.

Comment: Good point regarding getting closer to the hardware being optimal for emulation. Playing around with x86 virtual images (on my Mac and Windows laptops) of the Android OS has been a better experience than the emulator that ships with the SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Its true that eclipse is very slow and unstable but I still work on eclipse due to its Drag and drop design support. If you don't need that feature then go for IntelliJ IDE, It was the first IDE that I used for android development and is really better than eclipse in terms of stability, debugging and launching emulator.

As of the emulators, there are many new emulators available like [Youwave](http://youwave.com), [BlueStacks](http://BlueStacks.com) etc. but still you have to stick to android sdk emulator as it can be easily integrated with development and debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is probably the most used IDE by developers.
By providing Android plugins for Eclipse you don't have to ask developers to learn how to use a new environment (key bindings, windows, perspectives, buttons, ...).

I'm pretty happy to develop Android applications using the same IDE I use for other Java, C and C++ projects.

Regarding performances issues, I use it on Ubuntu and with 4GB ram and an i5 processor I don't find it slow or sluggish.

Answer (score 0):

A 'vanilla' Eclipse install with Android Development Tools runs fine for me (I run it on an i5 with 4GB of ram and also on Core Duo2 with 8GB of ram). 
You can also use a simple text editor for your Android projects if you want, or IntelliJ Idea community edition which is free and comes with Android support.

The problem with Eclipse (for me) is the number of plugins you've installed, if you just keep it down to the basics (java, c++) it works quite fast, some plugins are just CPU HOGS (FlashBuilder, STS ...)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a happy user of Eclipse on Mac and have been developing for Android for years now. Prior to that I was doing JSP/JAVA in Eclipse using the built in support for Tomcat - awesome stuff.

It's priceless that one IDE can help you do WEB, Dynamic WEB (JSP/JAVA), Mobile development (Android) all with the same UI. No need to learn new stuff - how can you go wrong with that!!

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio by Google. Is much better than Eclipse. It makes life easy and improves speed beyond your imaginations.